# gong-wpf-dragdrop on different type of observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, drag-and-drop

let say I have two ObservableCollection on my WPF app.

I need to drag one list of type "Module"

```
ObservableCollection<IModuleInfo> Modules
```

into a list of type "task"

```
ObservableCollection<TaskInfo> Tasks
```

if module is being dropped into task list, i will do  a conversion of module into task first, and then add the new task on the list.

i use gong-wpf-dragdrop, the default adorner is good. 
how do i do this? can't find the solution elsewhere.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" 
dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="False"
dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="5">
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                      
</ItemsControl>
```

the drop target will be:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"                                                          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="False"
dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"                                                    dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True"
dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"                                    
ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid> </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have implemented the IDropTarget on the view model,

but it seems like the

```
public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
```

won't accept a different types of object on drop.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the `IDropTarget` interface it will also require a `DragOver` method as well as the Drop method. Here is where you can do checking for types based on the `dropInfo.Data`, `dropInfo.SourceCollection`, and `dropInfo.TargetCollection`. It is true that you will no longer get the adorner for free, but it can be easily implemented:

```
public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if(dropInfo.Data.GetType() == typeof(MyType))
    {
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

After this you would handle the conversion and the addition to the target collection in the `Drop` method. Note that this `DragOver` method assumes you are not dragging several items at once, in which case you will need to do different type checking, but the adorner will be the same.